# oracle instant client zip file installation on linux

Tags: linux, oracle

I am trying to install oracle instant client on Linux. I don't want to go with rpm installation.
I downloaded below zip files from Oracle website and extracted to a single directory.

> instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip
>
> instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip
>
> instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip

I don't know what to do next. make or make install doesn't work. How do I proceed for installation. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow the install instructions http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html#ic_x64_inst

Comment: Thanks Jonas. That helps.